# DELETE query ears the last upload? [UPDATE]

Tags: php, button, sql-delete

I can not understand why the application delete the las upload.I am new in php and I hope to help me. Thank you.

Code:  HTML

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-centered">
        <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes3">
            <form class="form" method="POST">
            <input type="text" id="nmPic" name="nmPic" placeholder="име на снимката" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'име на снимката'"></br>
                <input type="text" id="price" class="priceFrom" name="priceFrom" placeholder="цена от" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'цена от'"></br>
                <input type="text" id="price" class="priceTo" name="priceTo" placeholder="цена до" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'цена до'"></br>
                <select name="picCat" id="picCat">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Изберете категория</option>
                    <option value="Детски">Детски</option>
                    <option value="Сватби">Сватби</option>
                    <option value="Рожден ден">Рожден ден</option>
                    <option value="18+">18+</option>
                    <option value="Други">Други</option>
                </select></br>
                <input type="text" id="numPic" name="numPic" placeholder="номер на снимката" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'номер на снимката'"></br>
                <input type="submit" name="showFilter" value="покажи" />
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Code: php

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12 col-centered pic">
        <form class='form' method='POST'>
        <?php
            if (isset($_POST["showFilter"])) 
            {
                $picName = $_POST['nmPic'];
                $priceFrom = $_POST['priceFrom'];
                $priceTo = $_POST['priceTo'];
                $picCat = isset($_POST['picCat']) ? $_POST['picCat'] : '';
                $numPic = $_POST['numPic'];

                $filter = " SELECT * FROM images WHERE status = '1'";
                if ($numPic && !empty($numPic)) {
                    $filter .= " AND id='$numPic'";
                }
                if ($picName && !empty($picName)) {
                    $filter .= " AND img_content='$picName'";
                }
                if ($picCat && !empty($picCat)) {
                    $filter .= " AND category='$picCat'";
                }
                if ($priceTo && !empty($priceTo)) {
                    $filter .= " AND price < '$priceTo'+1";
                }
                if ($priceFrom && !empty($priceFrom)) {
                    $filter .= " AND price > '$priceFrom'";
                }
                $resFilter = $connect->query($filter);


                if ($resFilter->num_rows > 0) {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resFilter))
                    {

                        echo        "<div class='col-md-3 picture'>

                                            <img class='child-img' src='".$row["picture"]." '/></br>
                                            <div class='number'>
                                            <span class='id'>№ ".$row['id']."</br>
                                             име: ".$row['img_content']."</br> категория: ".$row['category']."</br> 
                                             цена: ".$row['price']."лв.</br> 
                                             дата: ".$row['time']."ч.</br>
                                             </span>
                                             <input type='hidden' name='del' value=" .$row['id'].">
                                            <input class='btn btn-danger' name='delete' type='submit' value='истрии'/>
                                            </div>

                                    </div>";




                    }   
                }

            }       


     ?>

     </form>
    </div>
</div>
<form method="POST">
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['delete'])) 
        {

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE status = '1'";
                $res = $connect->query($sql);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $id = $_POST['del'];
                $dbhost = 'localhost';
                $dbuser = 'root';
                $dbpass = 'paspartu';
                $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
                if(! $conn )
                {
                  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }



                $sql = 'DELETE FROM images
                WHERE id='.$id;

                mysql_select_db('login');
                mysql_query($sql);


                mysql_close($conn);
            }   

        }
?>
</form>
```

If pressed the delete button `<input class="btn btn-danger" name="delete" type="submit" value="истрии">` , this delete the last upload image???
And can you tell me how to delete the image from upload folder "uploads/"? Thank you verry much.

Comment: Move the submit button into the `form` you create in the `while` loop.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: You have completely changed your question. Below answers are useless now.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't have an input in your form that's named "showFilter". You need to either rewrite or remove:

```
    if (isset($_POST["showFilter"]))
```

Comment: If you remove the `if (isset($_POST["showFilter"])) `, the filter will not work. I can not understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Try modified query delete

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `your_database`.`images` WHERE `your_database`.`id` = $del_id";
```

Comment: @Paspartu Check permission database on user. Try delete manualy in phpmyadmin. If delete does work you can copy query and past on you application.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your `submit` button is in separate `form` tag. That is why the button is responsible only for the first parent form and if it is pressed the page is only reloaded. It should be placed in the general form you use, so that it will be related with the general form action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take your submit button inside the form. You have used two different forms. It is the problem.

Try to write your code as below:-

```
 <?php
    // Take div and form tag outside the loop
    echo  "<div class='col-md-3 picture'>
        <form class='form' method='POST'>";

    // Loop start
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resFilter))
    {                                     
        echo "<img class='child-img' src='".$row["picture"]." '/></br>
                    <div class='number'>
                    <span class='id'>№ ".$row['id']." 
                    <input class='check' name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value='". $row['id']."'></br>
                     име: ".$row['img_content']."</br> категория: ".$row['category']."</br> 
                     цена: ".$row['price']."лв.</br> 
                     дата: ".$row['time']."ч.
                     </br></span>
                    <br></div>";


    }  
    // Loop End
?>
   <!-- submit button -->
    <input class="btn btn-danger" name="delete" type="submit" value="истрии маркираните">


     <?php  
        // end div and form tag outside the loop
        echo "</form>
              </div>";                   
        if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
            foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $del_id){
                $del_id = (int)$del_id;
                $sql = "DELETE FROM images WHERE id = $del_id"; 
                mysql_query($sql);
            }
            header('Location: admin.php');
        }
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Could you please not just write code and submit it as answer? **Explain** what you changed.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois: Thanks for your suggestion. I have added comments.